# Wordpress with Polylang plugin. Subpages switch giving error 404

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with my polylang plugin on subpages.
When I am trying to switch language (I want to go to home page after switch) from e.g `http://localhost/wordpress/projects_pl/` ("wordpress" is my main folder) after attempt to change language my url looks like: `http://localhost/wordpress/http://localhost/wordpress/home-en/` and give me ofc 404 page error. I don't know why this url looks like that. Maybe someone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have check the.htaccess which enable rewriting url. I got the same error 404 when open a sub pages. i just fixed it by the way, remove the access, and make the root wordpress folder writable to allow wordpress generate to new .htaccess.